# How to properly pass args array to method in java?

Tags: java, arrays, args

I'm trying to pass all command line arguments to a method. I get an error on `String a = method(args[]);`.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        String a = method(args[]);
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    static String method (String[] args){
        String b = args [0];
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's `method(args);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `[]` brackets. They are part of the type, not the parameter's identifier:

```
String a = method(args);
```

Type: `String[]` ("array of strings")

Parameter name: `args`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `String a = method(args[]);` with `String a = method(args);`

You do not have to include `[]` while passing the array.

Answer (score 1):

In your case args is already an array, so you just need to pass it in the method.

`String a = method(args[]);` this is wrong

`String a = method(args);` // remove []